# How to multi select relationship field on a channel form

Tags: safecracker, relationships, related-entries

Just trying to get my head around something.

Lets say I have two channels, one is salespeople and one is courses.

How would I create a multiple selection to courses for one salesperson?

I have the relevant fields setup in EE but I just cant figure out how to get this onto a form. I can see all of the salespeople and assign and remove them from one or main courses in the back end, so I know that the relationship is working correctly.

Everything I have tried doesn't work......

more than happy to purchase an add-on.

Any help would be much appreciated it.

Comment: What version of EE ? What 'relationship' module (native or playa)? Whats your template code look like?

Comment: I had my relationships around the wrong way! once I sorted that out it worked perfectly.